# Typescript+antd Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"" | "warning" | "error" | undefined'

Tags: typescript, antd

```
import ErrorText from '@/components/shared/ErrorText'
import { Input } from 'antd'
import { InputProps } from 'antd/lib/input'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledInput = styled(Input)``

const InputWrapper = styled.div`
margin: 15px 0;
`

function AntdInput({ text, isError, ...props }: { text: () =>             
JSX.Element; isError: string[] }) {
const statusInput = isError?.[0]
return (
    <InputWrapper>
        {text && text()}
        <StyledInput status={statusInput} {...props} />
        <ErrorText>{isError?.length && isError[1]}</ErrorText>
    </InputWrapper>
   )
}

export default AntdInput
```

This is a reusable component using antd's Input and i am passing a isError paramerter which will be a string("warning" | "error"), but abtd input's status only allows type '"" | "warning" | "error" | undefined', how can I solve this problem??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your component `isError` has the type `string[]` which does not match the union of the type of the `status` prop. One way so fix this would be changing the type of `isError` to `("error" | "warning"[])`.

```
function AntdInput({ text, isError, ...props }:
{ text: () => JSX.Element; isError: ('error' | 'warning')[] }) { // change this
    const statusInput = isError?.[0];
    return (
        <InputWrapper>
            {text && text()}
            <StyledInput status={statusInput} {...props} />
            <ErrorText>{isError?.length && isError[1]}</ErrorText>
        </InputWrapper>
    );
}
```

If you have access to the type of `status` you could also do

```
type Status = '' | 'error' | 'warning' | undefined;
type isError = Pick<{ [K in Status]: string }, 'error' | 'warning'>;
// --> "error" | "warning"
```

Comment: yes, the first solution helped solved the problem! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `isError` as `string[]` so TS is using that type.

You can either declare it as `isError: ("warning" | "error")[]`, but I think that `isError[0]` could be any string. Or you can use this type:

`isError: [string] | [string, "warning" | "error"]`

Notice: your `isError?.length` check is not checking that the array has an element at position `1`.

A third option would be to just to a cast to `"warning" | "error"`:

`isError[1] as "warning" | "error"`